# How to pick up the only integer data from an ArrayList of String 2

Tags: java, arraylist, integer

I read a text file and put the data into an ArrayList of String.

The data is like

```
China 12351235123
Korea 123532523
USA 12341235123
```

I just need those integer data to find the first digit of the integers.

I know how to find the first digit, but I don't know how I can pick up the only integer data.

Comment: Why did you ask the same question twice?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is, use this function for each input line:

```
public Integer getIntegerFromString(String str) {
    String res[] = str.split("\\s+");
    return new Integer(res[1]);  // since its on second position
}
```

or:

```
public Integer getIntegerFromString(String str) {
        String res[] = str.split("\\s+");
        return Integer.parseInt(res[1]);  // since its on second position
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string like:

(Not tested, i don't program with java from a while, so check if the sintax is correct)

```
String value = list.get(0);
String number = value.substring(value.indexOf(" ") + 1);
int integer = Integer.valueOf(number);
```

Comment: problem is you will only get one char from string with this substring, so for first line you will get only "1", not the whole "12351235123" number. Also, its not int.valueOf(number);, but Integer.valueOf(number)

Comment: You are wrong, when you use substring with only the first parameter you get it from the first position to the end of the string. For the second part i will correct it.

Comment: sorry, my mistake, somehow I sow comma instead of plus...

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Char.IsDigit method